# How to setup multi tenancy in ASP.NET 5 Web API and Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building a backend service using ASP.NET5's Web API & EF7 to setup a multi tenancy database structure. The requirements are as follows:

- API endpoints are the same for all tenants,
- each tenant has its own database containing tenant specific data,
- all tenants use the same database structure, therefore the same DbContext classes can be used across all tenants, but with different connection strings,
- each tenant database contains user information for authentication based on ASP.NET Identity.

I'm facing the following challenges at the moment:

- DbContext instances are not thread-safe, therefore their lifecycle should be short. This means I cannot simply store instances of DbContexts somewhere, but have to dynamically create and dispose instances when needed,
- It must be possible to add or remove tenants dynamically, preferably without restarting the service,
- EF7 migrations need to work.

To enable the service to dynamically add or remove tenants, my current implementation is based on a JSON config file, which contains all the tenant connection strings in key-value pairs, like this:

```
{
   "Tenants": [
      { "Tenant1": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Tenant1;integrated security=True;" },
      { "Tenant2": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Tenant2;integrated security=True;" }
   ]
}
```

This configuration is then used to setup a ContextFactory. This factory uses a store of DbContextOptions in order to dynamically create DbContext instances when needed and therefore achieve the necessary short lifecycles. The factory is defined as follows:

```
public class TenantContextFactory : ITenantContextFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The tenant configurations store.
    /// </summary>
    private IDictionary<string, DbContextOptions> tenants;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new TenantContextFactory
    /// </summary>
    public TenantContextFactory()
    {
        tenants = new Dictionary<string, DbContextOptions>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a tenant configuration with the store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The tenant id.</param>
    /// <param name="options">The context options.</param>
    public void RegisterTenant(string id, DbContextOptions options)
    {
        if (!tenants.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            tenants.Add(id, options);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a DbContext instance for the specified tenant.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of DbContext to create.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="id">The tenant id.</param>
    /// <returns>A new instance of the desired DbContext</returns>
    public T GetTenantContext<T>(string id) where T : DbContext
    {
        DbContextOptions options;
        if (tenants.TryGetValue(id, out options))
        {
            // get the type of the desired DbContext and return a new instance
            // with the DbContextOptions as the constructor parameter
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), options);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

During the configuration phase, the ContextFactory is being filled with the tenant information using an extension method like this:

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds multi tenancy to the service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The service collection</param>
    /// <param name="config">The configuration object</param>
    public static void AddMultiTenancy(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        var tenantContextFactory = new TenantContextFactory();

        // get the information from the JSON file
        var tenants = config.GetSection("Tenants");
        var values = tenants.GetChildren();
        foreach (var key in values)
        {
            foreach (var item in key.GetChildren())
            {
                // get the correct name of the config node
                var tenantId = item.Key.Split(':').Last();

                // and the connection string
                var connectionString = item.Value;

                // create the OptionsBuilder and configure it to use SQL server with the connection string
                var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

                // and register it with the factory
                tenantContextFactory.RegisterTenant(tenantId, builder.Options);
            }   
        }

        // register the factory with the DI container
        services.AddInstance(typeof(ITenantContextFactory), tenantContextFactory);
    }
}
```

The factory can then be injected as a service to any controller or service that needs it and instantiates the desired contexts correctly.

So far so good. The following questions remain:

**How to integrate EF7 migrations? (solved)**

Trying to add migrations I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database providers are
>   configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring
>   in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up
>   services.

Since the number of tenants is dynamic, I cannot specify a connection string directly in the DbContext class, or use the AddDbContext method to statically register DbContexts with a single database.

When I do supply a static connection string, the migrations get created successfully, but when I then try to use my dynamic approach, those migrations are not applied to the databases in use and I have no way to specify a connection string in the EF shell commands in order to execute migrations manually or via a shell script. I would basically have to rewrite the configuration code once per tenant, recompile and then use a shell command to execute the migrations, which is not a worthwhile option.

**SOLUTION:**

The Contexts to be migrated by using the following snippet for every context you want to use:

```
using (var context = tenantContextFactory.GetTenantContext<MyContext>(tenantId))
{
     context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

This checks the database automatically if the schema is compliant with the latest migrations, and applies it when not.

**How to integrate [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)?**

The authentication process needs to be tweaked to log in users correctly.

I'm on it right now and will post updates on my progress here.

**How to change tenants at runtime?**

This ties into the previous questions. How can I ensure that I can safely add or remove tenants by editing the config file without having to restart the service? Is that even possible?

**EDIT:**

I've found the solution to the migrations problem in EF7. The next challenge is ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: With your requirements it seems that perfect solution would be to use one database for all the tenants. It's perfectly viable solution. Read up this post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: Why you chosen this option different DB for each tenant? any bad exp in past?

Comment: The issue with a single database is versioning and data sensitivity. The tenants are mostly large companies who value data security highly and wouldn't want their data to be mixed with others. In addition, not every tenant would want to receive updates immediately because of possible training effort involved, so I need to be able to run older versions.

Comment: "API endpoints are the same for all tenants" - any chance you can create a seperate endpoint (application) per tenant? Solves pretty much every problem and allows for custom code.

Comment: @HenkMollema this would basically give information away about how many tenants the service has and where to reach them. this would add another secrurity risk and is therefore not an option.

Comment: @maxmantz I don't follow you.. I meant one service per tenant. Just a different application. How does that expose any information?

Comment: Can you separate out your authentication from the data?  For instance you could have a separate database which store details about each tenant such as username password, which tenant that user belongs too etc. but not their personal data.  
You would authenticate against this using an extended asp.net identity which would include some method of storing the name of the server, database and any other connection details applying the necessary security around these stored details.  This would allow you add and remove tenants without having to restart the service.

Comment: @HenkMollema Maybe I misunderstood your suggestion :) How would this work though? I would have to give tenant A an application endpoint, say www.serviceurl.com/tenantA and give tenant B another application endpoint www.serviceurl.com/tenantB. This would add a security concern because every tenant can be reached independently, instead of having a single endpoint which handles all tenants and gives no such information away.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. We usually host the application on a sub domain of the tenant.

Comment: @Stig Thanks for the suggestion. Realising something like this is the plan, but I will have to get EF7 to work first before I can get into details about this. I will keep this question updated to address these concerns once I get to them.

Comment: You have big customers who want their data isolated and want to be able to upgrade independently, yet you want to force them into a multi tenant single installation. That makes no sense to me. Seems like they should each have separate installations of the app without need for multi tenancy. Multi tenancy makes more sense to me if all the sites belong to one customer.

Comment: @JoeAudette This might sound unintuitive but it has (rarely) happened, that a few customers wish to update independently. Those would then receive their own applications. But for the most part this is not an issue.

Comment: _In addition, not every tenant would want to receive updates immediately because of possible training effort involved, so I need to be able to run older versions._ - I don't see how that can be done with a single application. I think migrations-wise you are on an all-or-nothing scenario.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera True, but for the small amount of tenants this applies to, I could simply remove their database from the main application and start a legacy version hosted on their intranet or other endpoint by using my approach. Having a single database for all tenants would make this a lot harder. As I've stated previously this is a minor concern. Security is a much more prominent issue.

Comment: Ok, so being able to run migrations separatedly is not really an issue. Still not clear what's your real problem: do you want to upgrade automatically all databases for your tenants when you upgrade your application, or do you want to be able to identify if a database is up-to-date, and probably upgrade that database using migrations?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera automatic migrations or manual migrations would both be fine, but right now my understanding is that I would have to rewrite the static code in my app configuration one tenant at a time to get a single migration to target multiple databases. This is definitely not something I want to do.

Comment: Well, I haven't done anything in your particular scenario, but it seems likely to me that you should be able to create your own configuration provider and access that when you want to run a migration. In EF6 you could specify the connection / configuration to use via a parameter, I guess there should be a similar facility to do this in EF7. Sorry for not being of real help.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera after looking through the EF7 commands, I cannot find an option to specify a connection string when creating a migration. Otherwise your idea would've solved my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90472/discussion-between-maxmantz-and-leonardo-herrera).

Answer (score 0):

As many have suggested it would be a lot cleaner to have one database.
See my comment in the discussions..

In the database have a Provider/Source Table.

Then create Repo's which have to accept a SourceId.

```
public interface IRepository<T>    
{        
    T GetById(int sourceid, int id);
}

public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public TEntity GetById(int sourceId, int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(sourceId, id);
    }
}
```

I know this would require you to have SourceId on basically every table.

I know this isn't the answer your looking for but maybe something to think about.

For me the code quite ambitious and will be very complex to maintain.

But I do hope you get it right!

**Update**

```
using(var context = new MyContext(DbHelper.GetConnectionString()))
{

}

public static class DbHelper
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //some logic to get the corrosponding connection string
        // which you are wanting  this could be based of url
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement :) It seems like your approach would force me to create a repository class for every entity I wish to save to a database. This would mean significant extra effort.

Comment: All entities would hinge of BaseRepository, So Product: BaseRepository, User: BaseRepository, Order: BaseRepository.... so it wouldnt be that much...

Comment: Personal I don't get you, You could make _dbContext have a public accesser... but that would be defeating the point of a repo. With regard to you edit, I do not know if it is true or not whether you can not modify the connection string of the Dbcontext once created.... but I would say that's a gd thing. Let say you get a request.... create a repo... why in that request would you change connection?

Comment: The problem is that i don't want a single instance of DbContext to be used on multiple database interactions. http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/ explains exactly what I mean. It concerns EF6 but such resources are not yet available for EF7, but I assume the concept hasn't changed that drastically.

Comment: Sorry tried really hard to read that whole link...(read about 6.5-8) was way to long. So have a single DbContext and just pass different connection strings to it. Have a method GetConnectionString() which returns the connection string applicable for the request. Then creates a DbContext with that connection string....Problem solved?

Comment: No because a DbContext is not thread-safe. When two services have access to a single DbContext instance and one is modifying data, then the other changes the model or calls `SaveChanges()`, all sorts of strange things will happen.

Comment: Your design is wrong if you are doing that! 1 context to a thread. Change your design. new up the context in the foreach parallel rather than outside of it.... or the service instance. Create a new service instance in the parallelism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90519/discussion-between-maxmantz-and-seabizkit).